# What is the French adjective for when a person is no longer able to feel emotions i.e. when emotions no longer appear in their heart/chest?

Tags: adjectifs

What is the French adjective for when a person is no longer able to feel emotions i.e. when emotions no longer appear in their heart/chest?

**Scenarios**

**Person 1**: I heard of the passing away of his child. How is he?

**Person 2**: He is …

**Person 1**: I heard his partner broke his heart. How is he?

**Person 2**: He is …

I provided the above scenarios so that you can immediately understand the state that I’m talking about but often people experience this state even though the above scenarios have not occurred to them.

**Therapist**: Things are going well in your life. You must be happy.

**Patient**: Even though my life has always been running smoothly, I haven’t felt any emotions for a while. That is, emotions no longer appear in my heart.

If there is no one word adjective, then that is okay. Please can you inform me if this is the case.

Thank you!

**Clarifications**:

To clarify, the father isn’t unaffected by his child’s death. It’s simply that due to his child’s death, he has been unable to feel any emotion thereafter. That is, emotions no longer appear in his heart/ches thereafter.

Comment: What word would you use for that in English?

Comment: I think the correct word would be numb.

Comment: Maybe léthargique? Not exactly the same thing but expresses a similar idea.

Comment: Thank you for this @Simon ! I’m starting to think that there is no explicit adjective.

Comment: [Please capitalize the word French. ]

Comment: https://www.cerveauetpsycho.fr/sd/psychologie/l-alexithymie-ou-le-silence-des-emotions-5520.php

Comment: @ Lambie Thank you for telling me about the capital letter. Ugh, I always make this mistake! Also thank you for the link. It’s time I put my comprehension to test. 

Comment: If I were to translate "numb" into French I would say *insensible* but in most cases I'd feel the need to add *insensible **à toute émotion***. If you want to lay stress on the change of state after the event using a past participle (as a passive) might be an alternative. Then I'd suggest  *vidé de toute émotion*,   (*insensibilisé* or *désensibilisé* wouldn't work in your case).

Comment: @None … *insensibilisé* ou *désensibilisé* induit un acte perpétué par un tiers sur le père, et non pas l'émotion excessive, insurmontable et sidérante causée par la perte brutale et contre nature de vivre la mort d'un de ses enfants … souffrance endurée souvent plus totalement par la mère : on pourrait parler de ***burn-out émotionnel***

Comment: @Personne tout à fait, c'est pour ça que toute proposition allant dans dans ce sens  doesn't work.

Comment: The English: "I haven’t felt any emotions for a while. That is, *emotions no longer appear in my heart"*. is not really idiomatic. So, what's he point? We would say: I haven't felt anything for a while. My heart is broken.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean that the person is "frozen", unable to express emotions but internally overwhelmed by the situation, you can use ***sidéré***.

If the person doesn't look to feel emotions, regardless of whether they are internally affected or not, that might be: ***apathique***, ***de marbre***, ***impassible***, ***indifférent*** plus a few other you can found in Personne's comment.

If the person doesn't care about anything that they should, you can also use the adjective *[**je-m'en-foutiste**](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/je-m%27en-foutiste)*.

If the person was affected by their child death but that was such a shock than nothing else affect them since then, you might say they are ***prostré*** or ***dans un état de torpeur***.

Comment: ***Insensible, amorphe, indifférent, inerte, atone, inexpressif, passif*** parmi les synonymes que le *petit* papa *Robert* a placé dans les souliers de CFrench, presque "50[/7] nuances de gris”aille émotionnelle pour une personne qui à l'émoi vital ***frigide*** :-)

Comment: @Personne Du moment qu'il n'y a pas *désensibilisé* dedans, ça me va ;-)

Comment: I feel now maybe I could have chosen a better scenario but I am looking for the adjective which describes the internal state mentioned in my question. Nonetheless, your answer is really insightful @jlliagre ! Thank your ever so much!

Comment: You could have indeed. Your examples, especially the first one, are definitely not what can help to immediately understand the feeling you are talking about. It is on the opposite very unexpected for me for a person to be unaffected by the death of their child, the reason why I suggested *sidéré* which somewhat matches the second definition of numb: *unable to think, feel, or react normally because of something that shocks or upsets you*. *Indifférent* and *apathique* can also match the internal state you are talking about.

Comment: @jlliagre Regarding the first scenario, I’m not saying that the father is unaffected by their child’s death. I’m saying that his child’s death was such that the father no longer has the ability to feel emotions, that emotions no longer appear in his heart/chest after the passing of his child. I have included the clarification in my posting. Thank you for bringing this up!

Answer (score -3):

The past participle of the verb "désensibiliser" can be used for that idea of loss of emotion or inability to feel usual emotions.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9sensibilis%C3%A9))  **B.** − **Domaine de la sensibilité, de l'émotivité, de l'affectivité humaine**
> **1.** [L'obj. désigne une pers. ou un groupe] **Faire perdre ou empêcher toute réaction émotive à, rendre incapable de témoigner de la sensibilité, de l'intérêt à (un événement)**.
> ♦ Désensibiliser l'opinion; être désensibilisé à
> ♦ « Père pieusement décédé cette nuit onze heures. Tendrement unis dans prières. » Toute sa pensée demeurait impénétrable à ces nouvelles, désensibilisée et comme durcie de cocaïne. Malègue, Augustin,t. 1, 1933, p. 370.

([réf. 1, 2014 - Philosophie de la Nature](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Philosophie_de_la_Nature/zhs0EAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22est+d%C3%A9sensibilis%C3%A9%22&pg=PA180&printsec=frontcover) ) Un homme complètement coupé de la Nature est désensibilisé. Il est comme le dit souvent Krishnamurti, dangereux. Cruel par insensibilité.

([réf. 2, 2020 - Apaiser les 6 feux de notre souffrance: Un chemin vers le ...](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Apaiser_les_6_feux_de_notre_souffrance/RY_nDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22est+d%C3%A9sensibilis%C3%A9%22&pg=PT47&printsec=frontcover)) Pour le petit roi, la petite reine • La Séductrice : elle domine grâce à son pouvoir de séduction. • La Brute : elle fait régner la peur autour d'elle. • Le Roc : rien ne l'atteint, il est désensibilisé de ses émotions.

([réf. 3, 2017 - La vie d'un bipolaire: Fou, mais pas complètement](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_vie_d_un_bipolaire/zL--DgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22est+d%C3%A9sensibilis%C3%A9%22&pg=PA86&printsec=frontcover)) A cette époque où tout est désensibilisé, où les émotions n'ont plus leur place, où les souffrances intérieures ne sont plus exprimées, où l'essentiel est perdu, où les relations humaines sont dénaturées, il reste cependant une partie

([réf. 4, 2010 - Les bienveillantes de Jonathan Littell: Études réunies par](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_bienveillantes_de_Jonathan_Littell/AdJcxINBx5YC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22est+d%C3%A9sensibilis%C3%A9%22&pg=PA44&printsec=frontcover) )  …lui aussi, soumis à un processus d'anamorphose dans la mesure où la perte de sa capacité à ressentir ce qui touche autrui, fait de lui, rien de moins, qu'un autre homme; qu'il le veuille on non, le bourreau est désensibilisé.

([réf. 5, 2020 - Faire la paix avec sa famille](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Faire_la_paix_avec_sa_famille/FFMEEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22est+d%C3%A9sensibilis%C3%A9%22&pg=PT52&printsec=frontcover)) Au-delà de cette désolation généralisée, Marine constate que chacun s'est désensibilisé. Lorsqu'elle découvre que son mari la trompe de façon répétée, elle est étonnée elle-même de ne rien ressentir : ni jalousie, ni révolte,

([réf. 6, 2020 - À notre ultime envol](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/%C3%80_notre_ultime_envol/YLTfDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22est+d%C3%A9sensibilis%C3%A9%22&pg=PT11&printsec=frontcover)) Je ne sais pas si cet homme est désensibilisé à ce genre de choses, ou s'il est persuadé que nous étions en sécurité. —Je, euh... Ma voix chevrote, mon corps tremble, et je le laisse me remettre sur pied. — Oui, je crois.

([réf. 7, 1998 - Le labyrinthe de Versailles: parcours critiques de Molière à](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_labyrinthe_de_Versailles/_dnnehgGDowC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22est+d%C3%A9sensibilis%C3%A9%22&pg=PA196&printsec=frontcover)) Il est désensibilisé après tant d'années de mauvais traitements , ne songeant qu'à sa propre survie .

([réf. 8, 2014 - Stratégies de domestication d'un peuple. BMW comme armes de ...](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Strat%C3%A9gies_de_domestication_d_un_peuple/1VUJCwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22est+d%C3%A9sensibilis%C3%A9%22&pg=PA173&printsec=frontcover)) Ici par contre, le peuple est désensibilisé, aseptisé. Il devient apathique et manifeste une attitude d'indifférence prononcée devant des événements qui mettent en péril son existence et son destin.

Comment: — **-1** :  Cf. commentaires associés à la question.

Comment: La désensibilisation est une action volontaire ou une atteinte à la faculté d'éprouver des sensations, mais absolument pas un retour (ou en l'occurrence une absence de retour) de la part de cette aptitude.

Comment: @Dfaure Être désensibilisé sur le plan des émotions ou de certaines émotions peut être le résultat d'une action consciemment accomplie dans le but de se désensibiliser (cependant, si mystérieuse—Qui peut être maitre de ses émotions au point de les erradiquer ? Mais passons…) ou d'une atteinte (qui peut être le résultat  accessoire d'une action personnelle (bourreau), ou bien plus souvent  de l'action d'un autre agent). Je suis essentiellement d'accord là-dessus. Ce qu'il y de  pertinent dans ce qui suit, l'absence de retour, est une conséquence du fait que l'aptitude a été supprimée, (1/2)

Comment: @DFaure  c'est à dire, du fait que l'on est  depuis un certain temps incapable de ressentir, c'est à dire « unable to feel » dans les mots du PO, ce qui est « désensibilisé ». Je n'emploie pas « désensibilisé » du tout dans le sens de « absence de retour » des facultés émotives, mais je l'emploie, comme dans les exemples, dans le sens de suppression de ces facultés. (2/2)